# Webapp2 + WTForms issue: How to pass values and errors back to user?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2, wtforms

I am having a problem with webapp2 and wtforms. More specifically I have defined two methods in two different handlers, called:

- `create`, which is a GET method listening to a specific route
- `save`, which is a POST method listening to another route

In the `save` method I validate my form and if fails, I want to redirect to the `create` method via the `redirect`_to method, where I can render the template with the form. Is this possible with any way? I found an example on how this can be done if the same handler with `get` and `post` methods, but is this possible in methods of different handlers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work if the routes are part of the same app.

But why not using a single handler with get and put and a method _create, which can be called (self._create instead of a redirect) by get and put to render the template with the form. It is faster than a browser redirect and you can pass arguments in an easy way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as you can see from my question, the thing is if this can be done with my current structure. I have done it with the approach you propose, but this is not something I want for my project structure. Thanks again!

Comment: OK. The reason of my proposal is : I do not like redirects. When I handle multi-page forms I try to use the same URL for every page request and dispatch the handler methods using a state. This makes page traversing easy (without redirects resulting in new requests).

Comment: Hey again! I understand the reasons for your proposal, as I have already mentioned in my question. However the question remains: Is what I want possible with the structure I propose? If it is not, probably I will follow the other solution, as already had.

Comment: Yes, sending a browser redirect is an incredibly awful solution to an internal code architecture problem. Don't do that.